# Regarding property in apache camel (2.13.0) route?

Tags: apache-camel

I have a a property in a camel route as follows

```
<camel:setProperty propertyName="xxxKey">
        <camel:simple>some value</camel:simple>
</camel:setProperty>
```

I wanted to know whether this property is shared between multiple instances of the same camel route ?

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not.

Properties represent part of the state of the current camel `Exchange`.